# The Apple of Eden and its uses

Tags: assassins-creed

In Assassin's Creed, everyone's end-game is to find the Apple of <strike>McGuffin</strike> Eden.

Apparently, it either has the seeds of disobedience, or some genetic code of free-will (probably extracted with Hashashin technology from 5 centuries ago), or a mixture of these.

Sofia Rikkin wants to study it to erase violence in men. I'm guessing the idea is to study the *genetic footprint* and learn what genomes are linked to hereditary violence, and from there work on a human genome project to influence such genes.

Alan Rikkin, however, decides he wants to eradicate the Assassins. I don't understand that. How does the Apple allow him to do so? Why is that still relevant to the Templars, when the Assassins are all but wiped out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assassins are the epitome of Free Will and Violence in the world. The Templar goal is to eliminate both. Sofia thinks that she can eliminate violent behavior without affecting free will. Alan doesn't and full embraces the Templar creed.

To Alan, the Assassins are the worst of what he wants to get rid of, the last barrier to a single rule under the Templars.

As they don't actually know what the apple actually is or does, how he will do that is a guess.  Genetically engineering free will out is one way. Generic targeting of people with the gene is another.

Comment: the apple in the games is capable of mind control (it's how the precursors controlled human slaves); I think there were hints of that kind of thing in the movie, e.g. putting the apple on a satellite and "broadcasting" it to the world.

Comment: @KutuluMike satellite? What? I don't recall that at all. Sofia even said they didn't know what it was, if it was celestial or alien, etc.

Comment: I could be conflating the movies and the games in my head, that's entirely possible.